# Books to learn objective-C for an experienced programmer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I am an experienced C++, C# programmer on Windows platform and would like to learn Objective-C to try out developing on the Mac and iPhone.

What books do you recommend me to start out with?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the quick answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reading [Learn Objective-C on the Mac](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218150) and find it good.

Comment: This is only useful if you are knowledgeable of C. I tried this, and it didn't fill in the gaps well enough...

Answer (score 7):

[Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619) by Aaron Hillegass is great for learning Mac programming.

Comment: I second Steve's comment. I just love this book as a guy moving from Microsoft environment to iPhone SDK dev.

Answer (score 5):

My favorites are:

- Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X, I have the 2nd and 3rd editions.
- Cocoa Programming by Daniel Steinberg
- Programming in Objective-C 2nd edition by Stephen Kochan. The 2nd edition adds the Objective-C 2.0 features: garbage collection, properties, and so on. I am not yet sure I like his approach of explaining just Objective-C (barely touching the Cocoa frameworks) because, even though Obj-C can be used without Cocoa, that'd be very unusual. However, it's a good book on the language itself.

Also, it's not in print yet, but Cocoa and Objective-C: Up and running (http://cocoabook.com/), by famed cocoa blogger Scott Stevenson looks promising as well, I've purchased access to the *beta* and is as good or better than his posts.
I also have (had) Cocoa Design Patterns, but unfortunately lost it in the train :(, so I can't honestly recommend it yet, but I liked the first chapter. I will buy it again, if that counts.

Links edited because of spam prevention prevented me posting them.

Answer (score 3):

To learn objective-c specifically -- not Cocoa or Cocoa touch -- I have and like:

[Programming in Objective-C 2.0 (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157)

[image: Programming in Objective-C 2.0 cover]

The reason that I like this book is because it doesn't assume extensive knowledge of C. Of course, knowing C -- or any C like programming language will help. But this presents Objective-C as Objective-C the programming language and not Objective-C the extension to C. I think this is important because C and Objective-C have different ideology. Yes, they share attributes but programming in C is a different *experience* from programming in Objective-C. Your book should reflect that. :-)

Comment: +1 This books covers the C background you need. I love Hillegass' book, but it focuses on Cocoa, with little coverage of Objective-C itself, especially when compared to this book.

Answer (score 2):

I liked [Learn Objective-C on the Mac](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430218159) and [Beginning iPhone 3 Development](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430224594). Between those two books you'll learn enough to be dangerous :)

I also started the [pragprog iPhone](http://pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development) book but preferred the Apress titles.

Answer (score 1):

[Beginning iPhone Development: Exploring the iPhone SDK](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430216263)

This book gets your feet wet in all the right areas.  Jeff LaMarche has a good Twitter feed too and appears to be very active in the iPhone community.

Answer (score 0):

I found this an excellent PDF when I was transitioning from other languages to Objective-C, as it compares a number of features from C++ and Java to Objective-C in a systematic manner:

http://ktd.club.fr/programmation/fichiers/cpp-objc-en.pdf